# How do I check if a pandas DataFrame is empty?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How do I check if a pandas `DataFrame` is empty? I'd like to print some message in the terminal if the `DataFrame` is empty.

Comment: len() doesn't work? It should return 0 for empty dataframe.

Answer (score 1101, accepted):

You can use the attribute `df.empty` to check whether it's empty or not:

```
if df.empty:
    print('DataFrame is empty!')
```

Source: [Pandas Documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.empty.html)

Comment: This seems like a shame, since you need to know that df is a pd.DataFrame. I'd like to know the motivation for not implementing bool() on pd.DataFrame.

Comment: @Quant - The documentation has a discussion on why __bool__ raises an error for a dataframe here: [link](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/gotchas.html#gotchas-truth).  Quote: "Should it be True because it’s not zero-length? False because there are False values? It is unclear, so instead, pandas raises a ValueError"

Comment: Much more faster approach is `df.shape[0] == 0` to check if dataframe is empty. You can test it.

Comment: This method would not work in all of the cases, as in some cases empty dataframe might be of NoneType.

Comment: @AnishJain To be clear, we are dealing with emptiness here, not nullity; if we want to find out whether a data frame is empty, we need to have a data frame object first; testing nullity is a different matter. If your data frame is NoneType to start with, you are not testing emptiness, you want to know whether you have an object or not.

Answer (score 144):

I use the `len` function. It's much faster than `empty`. `len(df.index)` is even faster.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10000, 4), columns=list('ABCD'))

def empty(df):
    return df.empty

def lenz(df):
    return len(df) == 0

def lenzi(df):
    return len(df.index) == 0

'''
%timeit empty(df)
%timeit lenz(df)
%timeit lenzi(df)

10000 loops, best of 3: 13.9 µs per loop
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.34 µs per loop
1000000 loops, best of 3: 695 ns per loop

len on index seems to be faster
'''
```

Comment: A DataFrame can be empty due either len(df.index) == 0 or len(df.columns) == 0 as well.

Comment: No, a data frame can contain columns but still be empty. len(df.index) == 0 is the best solution

Answer (score 36):

To see if a dataframe is empty, I argue that one should test for the **length of a dataframe's columns index**:

```py
if len(df.columns) == 0: 1
```

### Reason:

According to the [Pandas Reference API](https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.empty.html), there is a distinction between:

- an empty dataframe with 0 rows and *0 columns*
- an empty dataframe with rows containing `NaN` hence *at least 1 column*

Arguably, they are not the same. The other answers are imprecise in that `df.empty`, `len(df)`, or `len(df.index)` make no distinction and return **index is 0** and **empty is True** in both cases.

### Examples

Example 1: An empty dataframe with 0 rows and 0 columns

```py
In [1]: import pandas as pd
        df1 = pd.DataFrame()
        df1
Out[1]: Empty DataFrame
        Columns: []
        Index: []

In [2]: len(df1.index)  # or len(df1)
Out[2]: 0

In [3]: df1.empty
Out[3]: True
```

Example 2: A dataframe which is emptied to 0 rows but still retains `n` columns

```py
In [4]: df2 = pd.DataFrame({'AA' : [1, 2, 3], 'BB' : [11, 22, 33]})
        df2
Out[4]:    AA  BB
        0   1  11
        1   2  22
        2   3  33

In [5]: df2 = df2[df2['AA'] == 5]
        df2
Out[5]: Empty DataFrame
        Columns: [AA, BB]
        Index: []

In [6]: len(df2.index)  # or len(df2)
Out[6]: 0

In [7]: df2.empty
Out[7]: True
```

Now, building on the previous examples, in which the *index is 0* and *empty is True*. When reading the **length of the columns index** for the first loaded dataframe df1, it returns 0 columns to prove that it is indeed empty.

```py
In [8]: len(df1.columns)
Out[8]: 0

In [9]: len(df2.columns)
Out[9]: 2
```

**Critically**, while the second dataframe df2 contains no data, it is **not completely empty** because it returns the amount of empty columns that persist.

### Why it matters

Let's add a new column to these dataframes to understand the implications:

```py
# As expected, the empty column displays 1 series
In [10]: df1['CC'] = [111, 222, 333]
         df1
Out[10]:    CC
         0 111
         1 222
         2 333
In [11]: len(df1.columns)
Out[11]: 1

# Note the persisting series with rows containing `NaN` values in df2
In [12]: df2['CC'] = [111, 222, 333]
         df2
Out[12]:    AA  BB   CC
         0 NaN NaN  111
         1 NaN NaN  222
         2 NaN NaN  333
In [13]: len(df2.columns)
Out[13]: 3
```

It is evident that the original columns in df2 have re-surfaced. Therefore, it is prudent to instead read the **length of the columns index** with `len(pandas.core.frame.DataFrame.columns)` to see if a dataframe is empty.

### Practical solution

```py
# New dataframe df
In [1]: df = pd.DataFrame({'AA' : [1, 2, 3], 'BB' : [11, 22, 33]})
        df
Out[1]:    AA  BB
        0   1  11
        1   2  22
        2   3  33

# This data manipulation approach results in an empty df
# because of a subset of values that are not available (`NaN`)
In [2]: df = df[df['AA'] == 5]
        df
Out[2]: Empty DataFrame
        Columns: [AA, BB]
        Index: []

# NOTE: the df is empty, BUT the columns are persistent
In [3]: len(df.columns)
Out[3]: 2

# And accordingly, the other answers on this page
In [4]: len(df.index)  # or len(df)
Out[4]: 0

In [5]: df.empty
Out[5]: True
```

```py
# SOLUTION: conditionally check for empty columns
In [6]: if len(df.columns) != 0:  # <--- here
            # Do something, e.g. 
            # drop any columns containing rows with `NaN`
            # to make the df really empty
            df = df.dropna(how='all', axis=1)
        df
Out[6]: Empty DataFrame
        Columns: []
        Index: []

# Testing shows it is indeed empty now
In [7]: len(df.columns)
Out[7]: 0
```

Adding a new data series works as expected without the re-surfacing of empty columns (factually, without any series that were containing rows with only `NaN`):

```py
In [8]: df['CC'] = [111, 222, 333]
         df
Out[8]:    CC
         0 111
         1 222
         2 333
In [9]: len(df.columns)
Out[9]: 1
```

Answer (score 14):

I prefer going the long route. These are the checks I follow to avoid using a try-except clause -

1. check if variable is not None
2. then check if its a dataframe and
3. make sure its not empty

Here, `DATA` is the suspect variable -

```
DATA is not None and isinstance(DATA, pd.DataFrame) and not DATA.empty
```

Comment: This is redundant and bad practice if it's expected that the variable will be a DataFrame (which is what the OP implies) that is either empty or has rows. If it's not a DF (or if it's none), an exception should be thrown since something went wrong somewhere.

Comment: In Python, `try/except` is cheap and `if` is expensive. Python is neither Java nor C; here it's [Easier to Ask Forgiveness than Permission](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-eafp)

Answer (score 0):

1. If a DataFrame has got Nan and Non Null values and you want to find whether the DataFrame
   is empty or not then try this code.
2. when this situation can happen?
   This situation happens when a single function is used to plot more than one DataFrame
   which are passed as parameter.In such a situation the function try to plot the data even
   when a DataFrame is empty and thus plot an empty figure!.
   It will make sense if simply display 'DataFrame has no data' message.
3. why?
   if a DataFrame is empty(i.e. contain no data at all.Mind you DataFrame with Nan values
   is considered non empty) then it is desirable not to plot but put out a message :
   Suppose we have two DataFrames df1 and df2.
   The function myfunc takes any DataFrame(df1 and df2 in this case) and print a message
   if a DataFrame is empty(instead of plotting):

   ```
   df1                     df2
   col1 col2           col1 col2 
   Nan   2              Nan  Nan 
   2     Nan            Nan  Nan
   ```

and the function:

```
def myfunc(df):
  if (df.count().sum())>0: ##count the total number of non Nan values.Equal to 0 if DataFrame is empty
     print('not empty')
     df.plot(kind='barh')
  else:
     display a message instead of plotting if it is empty
     print('empty')
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess it depends on what the use case is but if you want to **check if a dataframe is truly empty** (so that you can assign whatever you want to it), then check it's shape:

```py
if df.shape == (0, 0):
    print('DataFrame is empty!')
```

---

`df.empty` [checks](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/bdc79c146c2e32f2cab629be240f01658cfb6cc2/pandas/core/generic.py#L2139) whether one of the axes (index or columns) is of length 0. In other words, it does the following check:

```py
len(df.index) == 0 or len(df.columns) == 0
```

[@Zero's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24933234/19123103) only checks if the index is of length 0, while [Sven's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54009974/19123103) only checks if the columns are of length 0.

---

I'll show examples where it may be relevant:

- Case `len(df.index) == 0`: As explained in Sven's answer, just checking if a dataframe has 0 length is not sufficient, as there may be some columns already defined and when actual values are assigned to a column, the previously defined column may show up. Note that `df.empty` is True in this case.

  ```py
  df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
  df.empty                     # True
  len(df.index) == 0           # True
  len(df.columns) == 0         # False
  df.shape == (0,0)            # False

  df['D'] = [1]

       A    B    C  D
  0  NaN  NaN  NaN  1
  ```
- Case `len(df.columns) == 0`: Checking if there are no columns defined is also insufficient as there may already be indices defined and assigning values that don't match the already defined length will raise an error. Note that `df.empty` is also True in this case.

  ```py
  df = pd.DataFrame(index=[0, 1, 2])
  df.empty                     # True
  len(df.index) == 0           # False
  len(df.columns) == 0         # True
  df.shape == (0,0)            # False

  df['D'] = [1]                # <--- ValueError: Length ... does not match ...
  ```

As you can see, in both cases above, `df.shape == (0,0)` is False; in other words, if that check returned True, we could've done both tasks without problems.