# How to check if pandas Series is empty?

Tags: python, pandas

How to check if pandas Series is empty?

I have tried this:

[How to check whether a pandas DataFrame is empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19828822/how-to-check-whether-a-pandas-dataframe-is-empty)

but it seems that Series has no property 'isempty'.

Comment: how about `len(ts) == 0`? edit: `ts.empty` should work

Comment: `len(ts)` worked for me `ts.empty` didn't

Answer (score 39):

I use len function. It's much faster than empty(). len(df.index) is even faster.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10000, 4), columns=list('ABCD'))

def empty(df):
    return df.empty

def lenz(df):
    return len(df) == 0

def lenzi(df):
    return len(df.index) == 0

'''
%timeit empty(df)
%timeit lenz(df)
%timeit lenzi(df)

10000 loops, best of 3: 13.9 µs per loop
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.34 µs per loop
1000000 loops, best of 3: 695 ns per loop

len on index seems to be faster
'''
```

Comment: I know :) That the question repeatedly asked in the novel, wasn't it?

Comment: THAT is a proper assessment!
Now the question is should one use just regular len(df) to not confuse future juniors looking at the code, or still len(df.index)?

Comment: The question is about a pandas `series`. The answer is about a `dataframe`; a better answer on checking if a dataframe is empty is `if len(df.columns) == 0` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19828822/how-to-check-whether-a-pandas-dataframe-is-empty/54009974#54009974

Answer (score 23):

I use this to check if a particular column in a dataFrame has no values or is empty:

```
len(df.col_name.value_counts()) > 0
```

Answer (score 19):

According to the Pandas [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22.0/basics.html#boolean-reductions) you need to use the `empty` property and not `isempty`

E.g.

```
In [12]: df.empty
Out[13]: False
```

Comment: also, according to the post that OP linked to, it's `empty` and not `isempty`. not sure why he didn't read that in the first place...

Comment: The question is about a pandas `series`. The answer is about a `dataframe`; a better answer on checking if a dataframe is empty is `if len(df.columns) == 0` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19828822/how-to-check-whether-a-pandas-dataframe-is-empty/54009974#54009974

Answer (score 10):

If NDFrame contains **only** NaNs, it is still not considered empty. See the example below.

**Examples**

An example of an actual empty DataFrame. Notice the index is empty:

```
>>> df_empty = pd.DataFrame({'A' : []})
>>> df_empty
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [A]
Index: []
>>> df_empty.empty
True
```

If we only have **NaNs** in our DataFrame, it is not considered empty! We will need to drop the **NaNs** to make the DataFrame empty:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [np.nan]})
>>> df
    A
0 NaN
>>> df.empty
False
>>> df.dropna().empty
True
```

[Source](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.empty.html)

Comment: An important distinction!

Answer (score 5):

### Long answer: it depends

Depending on your definition of empty, your answer may vary a lot, as indicated by the various other answers. I try to summarize, but first have some test DataFrames:

```
no_rows = pd.DataFrame([], columns=list('ABCD'))
no_cols = pd.DataFrame([], index=range(3))
only_na = pd.DataFrame(float('nan'), index=range(3), columns=list('ABCD'))
```

#### Empty == no rows

The currently most popular answer takes this approach: a DataFrame with 0 rows is empty:

```
def empty_no_rows(df):
    return len(df.index) == 0
```

#### Empty == no columns

Not mentioned yet, but equally valid would be the transposed definition:

```
def empty_no_cols(df):
    return len(df.columns) == 0
```

#### Empty == no values

No actually, what you care about are values! If you prefer a definition that can deal with both empty `index` **or** `columns`, the following definition would work:

```
def empty_no_vals(df):
    return df.values.size == 0
```

#### Empty == what pandas says

Why not live with pandas' own definition of emptiness, which for these test cases leads to the same results as the no values definition:

```
def empty_native(df):
    return df.empty
```

Pandas' own implementation basically just checks if `len(df.columns) == 0 or len(df.index) == 0`, and never looks at `values` directly.

#### Empty == not only NaN's

Finally, you might want to ignore `NaN` in your considerations:

```
def empty_nans(df):
    return df.dropna(how='all').empty
```

But actually, this opens the next can of worms, as you now must decide `how` and along which `axis` you want to discard values? I stick to the more conservative `all`, here. And once those values are dropped, you could now apply all of the above definitions to its result.

### Comparison

| DataFrame | empty_no_rows | empty_no_cols | empty_no_vals | empty_native | empty_nans |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `no_rows` | ✅ True | ❌ False | ✅ True | ✅ True | ✅ True |
| `no_cols` | ❌ False | ✅ True | ✅ True | ✅ True | ✅ True |
| `only_na` | ❌ False | ❌ False | ❌ False | ❌ False | ✅ True |

<sub>Editorial remark: I would call all those functions `is_empty_...`, but that leads to a comparison table that is too wide.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

This works for a single `pd.Series` e. g. a column of a `pd.DataFrame`:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 2), columns=list("AB"))
df["empty_series"] = np.nan

# this would lead to a non empty series
# df["empty_series"].iloc[0] = "foo"

# returns True of all values of series are NaN
print(df["empty_series"].isna().all())
```

Comment: Searching for _test pandas empty column_, I found this post on Series, and this answer in particular was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @sparrow I used this to test for datetime columns:

```
    if len(df.select_dtypes(include='datetime').iloc[0].value_counts()) == 0:
        print('DF DATETIME COLUMNS: ', len(df_dt.iloc[0].value_counts()))
```

None of the other methodes (a.any(), a.empty()...) worked.
select returns with a non-empty index but with empty columns so I think that's it.
I think it actually returns a series, hence the zero iloc.

Answer (score 0):

To check if a serie is empty I do the following:

```
df['your data'].notna().sum() == 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I will explain my experiment:

I had a code as following:

```
matched_this = pd.Series(matched_groups)
```

And sometimes matched_this was []. But match_this.empty was False.
So to solve this problem I used as follows:

```
if match_this[0]:
  # do ...
```

Answer (score 0):

##### Q: How to check if pandas Series is empty?

Many answers here are dealing with measuring an empty pandas dataframe. A pandas dataframe is not the same as a pandas Series. An individual pandas Series may change its length during a data manipulation process. It may be useful to verify the length of a Series directly, using either

1. `Series.empty`
2. `len()`
3. `len(Series.array)`

##### Short examples

Let's create 3 dataframes to compare the output when measuring the length of a Series

```py
>>> df0 = pd.DataFrame({'X' : []})
>>> df0
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [X]
Index: []

>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['np.Nan']})
>>> df1
   A
0  np.NaN

>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame({'B' : ['b']})
>>> df2
   B
0  b
```

The pandas Series `df0.X` is empty. Therefore,

```py
1. >>> df0.X.empty
   True
2. >>> len(df0.X)
   0
3. >>> len(df0.x.array)
   0
```

Each other pandas Series `pf1.A` and `df2.B` contains 1 value. Therefore,

```py
df1.A                       |  df2.B
----------------------------|----------------------------
1. >>> df1.A.empty          |   1. >>> df2.B.empty
   False                    |      False
2. >>> len(df1.A)           |   2. >>> len(df2.B)
   1                        |      1
3. >>> len(df1.A.array)     |   3. >>> len(df2.B.array)
   1                        |      1
```

Hence, to verify if a pandas Series is empty, e.g. for `df['A']`, one may use

```py
if df.A.empty == True:
```

```py
if len(df.A) == 0:
```

```py
if len(df.A.array) == 0:
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check the columns `id` you can try
`df[df["id"].isna()].shape[0] == 0`