# Removing empty dataframes inside a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dictionary called `frames` with dataframes in it which summarize my data source considering different factors.

Some of this combinations return empty summaries and those dataframes are empty.

My question is how can I remove these empty dataframes from my dictionary?
I tried the below but they still persist.

`new_frames = {k:v for (k,v) in frames.items() if v is not None}`

Thank you

Comment: can you post an example?

Comment: Pandas Dataframe? `new_frames = {k:v for (k,v) in frames.items() if not v.empty}`? Need more details: [ask], [mcve]

Comment: is it empty like `[]` or `None` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check whether a pandas DataFrame is empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19828822/how-to-check-whether-a-pandas-dataframe-is-empty)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
frames = {1: 10, 2: [], 3: []}

new_frames = {k:v for (k,v) in frames.items() if v != []}

new_frames
{1: 10}
```

If you have pandas dataframes:

```
new_frames = {k:v for (k,v) in frames.items() if not v.empty}
```