# Adjust variable if I have a empty table

Tags: python, pandas

I have a filtered dataframe:

```
börse2 = bör[(bör['Ausprägung'] == bor)].iloc[0:1, : ]
```

which in some cases looks like this (empty):

[image]

When i run the command:

```
bor2 = börse2.iloc[0]['Schlüssel']
```

I get the error:

> IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds

which makes sense, how can I see in this cases that `bor2= 111` for example? Is there another option instead of [try except](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/843277/how-do-i-check-if-a-variable-exists). The problem with try except is that there can also be another error, but I want to explicity only use it if my dataframe `bor2` is empty.

Comment: Can you not just use the empty method? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19828822/how-to-check-whether-a-pandas-dataframe-is-empty)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
börse2 = bör[(bör['Ausprägung'] == bor)]
```

And is necessary test empty dataframe use [`DataFrame.empty`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.empty.html):

```
if börse2.empty:
    print ('no match')
else:
    print ('match')
```

---

But if want match some first value of column `col` if match, else some default value, here `no match` use `next` with `iter` trick:

```
s = bör.loc[(bör['Ausprägung'] == bor), 'col']
first = next(iter(s), 'no match')
```