# To check if the list and dataframe is empty

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Is there a way to check if both list and dataframe is empty? I am using df.count() == 0 but is there a more efficient way to check the data frame and the list is empty.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check whether a pandas DataFrame is empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19828822/how-to-check-whether-a-pandas-dataframe-is-empty)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32707620/how-to-check-if-spark-dataframe-is-empty

Comment: len(df.head(1)) > 0 or df.head(1).isEmpty or df.take(1).isEmpty

Answer (score 0):

**Hope** this helped you, using:  `df.empty`  and  `not list`

```
import pandas as pd

list = [1,2,3,4]        #fulled list
df = pd.DataFrame(list) #fulled dataframe
print (df)

print(df.empty) #False
print(not list) #False

print("\n")

list = []               #empty list
df = pd.DataFrame(list) #empty dataframe
print (df)

print(df.empty) #True
print(not list) #True
```

**[Result]:**

> ```
>    0
> 0  1
> 1  2
> 2  3
> 3  4
> False
> False
>
>
> Empty DataFrame
> Columns: []
> Index: []
> True
> True
> ```