# I am trying to convert csv into xlsx fileI am getting an error "No columns to parse from file"

Tags: python, pandas, read.csv, linq-to-excel

My code :

```
 df=pd.read_csv("File.csv",header=None,delim_whitespace=True)
    df.to_excel("output.xlsx",sheet_name=sheet.name,index=False)
```

i can see File.csv has no data.How to avoid this error.(Data was extracted as csv format and saving in it as File.csv)

Error :

```
No Columns to parse from file
```

Comment: What is `sheet.name`?

Comment: while converting into excel,i need to name the sheet(sheet.name has other values like View1[sheet1])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to check what are your separators.
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

When using pandas separator parameter of read_csv fuction is by default ',' what are separators in your csv file? if they are for example semicolons, you need to specify it

Comment: Extracted data(File.csv) has no data in it.No seperator...I am reading multiple csv files...this is sample code.i am getting error on this

Comment: Then provide your code, not a 'sample one' - We can't figure the problem based on samples and not full informations

Answer (score 0):

After reading `File.csv`, check if the dataframe is empty:

```py
if df.empty:
    ...
```

See [How to check whether a pandas DataFrame is empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19828822/2038264) for other approaches

Comment: thanks..I tried the alter way like if df is empty then print the name else it convert into excel file..But still getting same error