# Create an exception for empty dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

how to use try: and raise exception: for empty dataframe.

```py
import pandas as pd

name_dict = {'name': [], 'score':[]}
df = pd.DataFrame(name_dict)
print(df)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19828822/how-to-check-whether-a-pandas-dataframe-is-empty - `if df.empty: raise Exception("whatever")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`pandas.DataFrame.empty`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.empty.html) attribute

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame()
if df.empty:
    raise Exception("DataFrame must not be empty")
```